# BASH Unmount multiple drives

Tags: macos, bash

I am working on a local login script for some Macintosh clients.  I would like to unmount a number of drives on the machine prior to attempting to mount them again, similar to what I do on Windows clients.  Listed below is the code that I have; however, I was curious if there was a way in which to optimize this or condense the code?

```
if [ -d "/Volumes/Share1" ]; then
    umount -f /Volumes/Share1
fi

if [ -d "/Volumes/Share2" ]; then
    umount -f /Volumes/Share2
fi

if [ -d "/Volumes/Share3" ]; then
    umount -f /Volumes/Share3
fi
```

This just seems bulky and kludgy and I am not sure how to make it any better.

Comment: I don't see any problem with it. Also, if you're redirecting `stderr` somewhere else, you can skip the `if` statements as `umount` will do nothing except throw an error saying such a partition doesn't exist.

Comment: Regarding the structure, it looks readable (without comments), which is good.

Comment: Use the built-in command : `diskutil unmountDisk disk1`. You don't have to check if it's mounted beforehand, just catch the error and continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
VOLUMES="/Volumes/Share1 /Volumes/Share2 /Volumes/Share3"

for volume in $VOLUMES ; do
 [ -d $volume ] && umount -f $volume
done
```

(You'd need some modifications to this to handle names with spaces in them though)

Answer (score 2):

A for loop?

```
for dir in /Volumes/Share[123]; do 
  if [ -d "$dir" ] ; then
    umount -f $dir
  fi
done
```

In real life, it's unlikely to be `Share[123]` you want to deal with, so I'd expect you want to put the actual list there, like

```
for dir in "/Volumes/My Share" "/Volumes/pr0n" "/Volumes/warez"; do
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use functions to reduce duplication:

```
unmount_if_necessary() {
    [ -d "$1" ] && umount -f "$1"
}

unmount_if_necessary /Volumes/Share1
unmount_if_necessary /Volumes/Share2
#...
```